# Are hyperbolas of the same eccentricity shaped different?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry, graphing-functions, conic-sections

It seemed like that shouldn't be the case, because as I understand it, figures retain their shape when each coordinate is scaled by the same factor. So if I'm keeping the eccentricity of the hyperbola $$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{a^2(e^2-1)}=1$$ constant and multiplying $a$ by, say, 3, it seems like both coordinates of each point would be similarly scaled by 3, and that the hyperbola would, as above, retain its shape.

But this doesn't seem apparent when I [graphed it](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cl6wtyxuks) (I used q for the eccentricity because Desmos thinks e is 2.71...). When you change a from the 'hyperbola' folder, you can see the hyperbola squeeze at the centre.

I know that, as with parabolas, it may not be immediately apparent that multiple figures are shaped the same. But if hyperbolas of different eccentricities *are* shaped similar - and the bit about uniform scaling not changing the shape is correct - why does it look like this?

And if either or both points are wrong, why so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the hyperbola with $a=3.2, e=1.34$
[image: a32]
Here is the hyperbola with $a=1.6, e=1.34$
[image: a16]
You say they are not similar because it is "squeezed in the center".

If we take the center part of the $1.6$ picture, and magnify by factor $2$ we get
[image: a16half]
And now it definitely does look like the $3.2$ picture, right?  If you superimpose them, they match exactly.

Comment: So since zooming in on the graphing calculator is just a 'uniform scaling' operation as described earlier, and since it does not change the shape, it can be used to see that both shapes are the same. I get this, thanks. Wish there was a more rigorous way to prove that radially shifting the points of a figure outward doesn't change it's shape; I only have an intuitive idea of it. It'd be great if you could link to any resource you have on that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all hyperbolas with the same given eccentricity are similar. Your reasoning is perfectly sound, but perhaps your eyes deceive you.

I had a look at your Desmos construction, and it is consistent with what we should expect to see. As parameter $a$ is changed, it acts as scale factor for a dilation. The curve crowds closer to the center as $a$ approaches zero. Well, of course it does. We should expect that behavior in a dilation.

The asymptotes are invariant. We should expect that too. They are lines through the center of dilation.